# How to have a defined number of boxes per line

Tags: html, css

I want to have only 5 boxes per line, and the next one goes to the next line.
Like this. Is it possible with CSS?

[image]

```css
.box {
  border-color: #32ff00;
  border-width: 4px;
  border-style: dotted;
  width: 170px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: yes, you need to use `grid` in css to achieve that. you can read documentation or watch tutorials on that for better understanding

Comment: @kazmi066 A grid layout is one way to do this, but it is not "needed".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep using `float` (as you did in the question), you can use this CSS rule for that purpose:

```
.box:nth-child(5n+1) {
  clear: left;
}
```

This will move every 5th-plus-1 `.box` (i.e. the 6th, 11th, 16th etc.) into a new line. Note that there must not be any other elements between them (on the same HTML level) for this to work.

(note: I made the boxes smaller to be able to show the result within the snippet window)

```css
.box {
  border-color: #32ff00;
  border-width: 4px;
  border-style: dotted;
  width: 80px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}

.box:nth-child(5n+1) {
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) or [Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) would make it simpler than using `float`. Here is for Grid, for example:

```css
.boxes {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 100px);
  gap: 1rem; /* to have some space between the boxes */
}
.box {
  border-color: #32ff00;
  border-width: 4px;
  border-style: dotted;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is rather traditional solution that is supported even by older browsers and does not require grid or flexbox.

- Wrap the boxes to a container with some (fixed, percent, `auto` etc.) width that limits the width of line with boxes. Note that container-width = box-width * box-per-line if you do not have spaces between them.
- Make the boxes `display: inline-block` (“position like a character”).
- **Remove all whitespace between boxes in HTML.** If you do not that, you will get spaces between the boxes. (You can also make the font size 0 in CSS instead of removing HTML whitespace.)
- If you want to support also narrower screens, just limit the width using `max-width: 100%`. Then, you are able to set the maximum number of the columns and the actual number of them will be automatically chosen depending on screen/parent element width.

For centering:

- Center the boxes in the container using `text-align: center` of the container.
- Reset the text alignment in the boxes, e.g. using `text-aling: left` on the boxes.
- Center the container itself using `margin: auto` (if its `position` is `absolute` or `relative`, use `margin: 0 auto`, so you do not get vertical centering). You are still free to set arbitrary top and bottom margins on the container. To add horizontal space around the boxes, use padding on the container.

```css
.container {
  width: 850px;

  /* Use less columns on narrow screens. */
  max-width: 100%;
  
  /* For centering. */
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.box {
  border-color: #32ff00;
  border-width: 4px;
  border-style: dotted;
  width: 170px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div><!--
  --><div class="box"></div><!--
  --><div class="box"></div><!--
  --><div class="box"></div><!--
  --><div class="box"></div><!--
  --><div class="box"></div><!--
  --><div class="box"></div><!--
  --><div class="box"></div><!--
  --><div class="box"></div><!--
  --><div class="box"></div><!--
  --><div class="box"></div><!--
  --><div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can set the `display` property of the parent element to `grid` and utilize `grid-template-columns` and `grid-template-rows` property like this

```css
#parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px
}

.box {
  border-color: #32ff00;
  border-width: 4px;
  border-style: dotted;
  width: 170px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS property would set the number of columns to 5 and the number of rows to 2.

Comment: In my opinion, using `grid` for this is an overkill. See also [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71539019) for more traditional solution.

Comment: @jiwopene Yes. I agree but using the grid layout keeps things simple when a large number of elements are involved. It is also much easier to style the children. But, one obvious downfall is that it's not supported my older browsers.

Comment: if I do not need support for older browsers, I would prefer flexbox `#parent` with fixed width, so it is easier to reflow the boxes when the screen resizes. (Well, with `repeat(…)`, the grid-based approach does not look so bad.)